# How To Reset useSelector Value or Array or Object to Empty React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a simple question. I am implementing the useSelector Hook React Native together with ReduxToolKit.
But now the problem when the useSelector have data or not empty and everytime I change my screen the useSelector data remain the same data.

I want when change screen my useSelector data to be empty array again.

How do I solve this problem ?

Thank You

**EDIT :**

**ApiChartingSlice.js**

```
export const ApiChartingDataThunk = createAsyncThunk(
    'ApiChartingData',
    async (data) => {        
        try {
            const {chart, ticker} = data;        
            const response = await ApiChartingData(chart, ticker);               
            return response;      
        } catch (error) {                 
            return console.log({ error: error.message });            
        }        
    }     
)

// status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
export const ApiChartingDataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ApiChartingData',   
    initialState: {
        apiData: [],
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers: {},   
    extraReducers: {                
        [ApiChartingDataThunk.pending.type]: (state, action) => {            
            state.playerList = {
                status: state.status = 'loading',
                apiData: [],
                error: {},
            };
        },
        [ApiChartingDataThunk.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: state.status = 'idle',                
                apiData: state.apiData = action.payload,
                error: {},
            };
        },
        [ApiChartingDataThunk.rejected.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: state.status = 'failed',
                apiData: [],
                error: action.payload,
            };
        },
    }
});
```

**ChartUserCard.js**

```
 const tickerData = useSelector(state => state.ApiTicker.apiData);


const checkTicker = useCallback(() => {                   
        dispatch(ApiTickerThunk(inputValue))        
        .unwrap()
        .then((originalPromiseResult) => {   
            // console.log(originalPromiseResult);
        })
        .catch((rejectedValueOrSerializedError) => {        
            console.log(rejectedValueOrSerializedError);                          
        });                       
        
        setStart(true);
    }, [dispatch, inputValue, tickerData]);
```

in Here : **const tickerData = useSelector(state => state.ApiTicker.apiData);**

I want to reset tickerData.

Comment: You need to provide a fully reproducible example. Otherwise how can we solve the problem?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I have provide the code detail. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: You can dispatch an action with empty data to update the reducer in your return part of useEffect, so that when a screen unmounts it updates the reducer to empty. Also why are using a global state if you want it to be empty initially on every screen? you can just create a local state on every screen and update it.

Comment: @this.arjun I just one to split my code and make it look tidy. so in one screen there will not to many code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank To @this.arjun.

```
const dataThunk = {chart: "", ticker: ""};    
const tickerThunk = "";

 const resetDataThunk = useCallback(() => {                   
        dispatch(ApiTickerThunk(tickerThunk));
        dispatch(ApiChartingDataThunk(dataThunk));        
    }, [dispatch]);
```

Just use dispatch empty data.

Comment: yes this is the right way, welcome :)